# Python and windows filesystem with none-ascii characters

Tags: python, windows, ntfs

I want to write a folder on a windows system, Vista and Win7 with NTFS file systems.
The folders may contain the characters å, ä and/or ö, "förjävligt" for example.

The python files and every string in it is currently in UTF-8, how do I convert it to suite the Windows file system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're working with normal Python 2 strings, you can simply convert them to Unicode

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
normalString = "äöü"

# Now convert to unicode. Specified encoding must match the file encoding
# in this example. In general, you must specify how the bytes-only string
# contained in "normalString" is encoded.
unicodeString = unicode(normalString, "utf-8")

with open(unicodeString, "w") as f:
    ...
```

and create the files using those Unicode strings. Python (and indirectly the Windows API) will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the strings really nice for working with in windows you can use this [safeFilenameCodec](https://svn.origo.ethz.ch/bobcat/src-doc/safefilename-module.html).  It is a subset of allowable characters, but you won't have to worry about any craziness getting by. And it has generous licensing.

Comment: That library should be called "uglyFilenamesCodec". It works but the filenames won't be very readable. I created a similar library for naming music files (escapes characters like \/:*?"<>| in the song title) - but I wouldn't use such a solution for *all* filenames. Anyway +1 for the suggestion.